# Doxygen: why is the first element of my enum class not properly copied with copydoc?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * @brief OpenGL renderer rescale types 
 */
enum class RescaleType {
    None, //!< No rescale
    Horizontal, //!< Rescale horizontally
    Vertical, //!< Rescale vertically
    Both //!< Rescale both
};

/**
 * @brief 
 * 
 * @param type Type of rescaling to apply. It can be one of the following:
 * - RescaleType::None @copydoc RescaleType::None
 * - RescaleType::Horizontal @copydoc RescaleType::Horizontal
 * - RescaleType::Vertical @copydoc RescaleType::Vertical
 * - RescaleType::Both @copydoc RescaleType::Both
 */
void    apply_rescale(RescaleType type);
```

When running doxygen, everything works fine except the first @copydoc

[image: Doxygen output]

What am I doing wrong here ? I am new to using Doxygen so maybe the mistake is obvious.

Edit: This was generated with Doxygen 1.9.2

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? I can reproduce the problem with the current doxygen version (1.9.2) and also with the current master version, so it looks like a bug to me. Please create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: When you would fill in the brief description of the function you would see documentation with `RescaleType::None` at the parameter as well.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the very long delay, I had to work from a machine without root access and could not get doxygen to work. I will create an issue when I get home.

Comment: An implementation for your problem has been made in the doxygen master version (1.9.3 (ab74ff26b0f9ba3f31d1dce605c4a1809ca9cb5c)) by @doxygen

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am very sorry I am very busy at the moment and I kinda forgot to make an issue. I am assuming it is no longer necessary? Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering: this was a bug and was fixed in commit ab74ff26b0f9ba3f31d1dce605c4a1809ca9cb5c and is now part of Doxygen release 1.9.3. Huge thanks to @albert for lightning fast patching :-)